# how can I integrate social auth library to my android studio project

Tags: android, maven, social-authentication

how can I intergrade [social auth](https://github.com/minafaw/socialauth-android) to my project I am using android studio

I am looking for any tutorial but I cant find any thing related to this topic

my tries : I tried to download jar file to import to my project from downloads

https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/downloads/list

I find its Deprecated

```
socialauth-android-sdk-3.0.zip  Deprecated - Check Home Page for New Downloads
```

I navigate to home page for new Downloads , but I find the same deprecated version

https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/downloads/detail?name=socialauth-android-sdk-3.0.zip&can=2&q=

is this best library for social authentication ?

I find some people recommend  [ASNE](https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE) but also I find message

**Sorry, but I freeze work on project for some time(I hope not long, nearly month) - too busy. I saw all Issues and will resolve them as soon as I can.
I checked project - current maven libs mostly works fine. For now I need help with Issues and open for pull requests - will check them and merge on weekends**.

any one can help me which library is better and tell me how intergrade it to my project

Answer (score 2):

If you want integrate not maven library in Android Studio Project, just put the jar file(s) in libs folder of your app module (create it if does not exists).

Then add

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

in dependencies of the build.gradle of your app module.